# Android: Use FusedLocationProviderClient to get location once?

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

With `FusedLocationProviderApi` being deprecated, I'm having a hard time using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get location of a user just once after a button click.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm having a hard time using FusedLocationProviderClient to get location of the user just once...

[FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient) has the following methods

- [getLastLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#getLastLocation()) that returns a location *"just once"*
- [requestLocationUpdates (LocationRequest request, LocationCallback callback, Looper looper)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback,%20android.os.Looper))
- [requestLocationUpdates (LocationRequest request, PendingIntent callbackIntent)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

where [LocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest), in its turn, has the [setNumUpdates (int numUpdates)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setNumUpdates(int)) method. By passing `numUpdates = 1` you'll *"get location of the user just once"*.

Answer (score 1):

New version of `play-services-location` added the method `getCurrentLocation()`

This is how I am getting location

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

In my Fragment

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
```

Then After getting location permission code this is how I am getting location

```
  fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, null)
  fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        textView.setText(getLocationNameFromLatLon(location.latitude, location.longitude))
                    }
                }
```